# Owncloud data folder in /home

Tags: linux, permissions, file-permissions, owncloud

I've installed an owncloud server to share it with 7 others people. I have set a symbolic link  from their data folder to their home (/var/www/owncloud/data/$USER -> /home/$USER/owncloud ). So every user needs to have the rights to write into a www-data folder, but if I add the users into the www-data group, they will be able to see documents from each others.
I want every user's folder to be private but www-data must have read/write permissions. How can I do that?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With basic permissions, this isn't possible. You'll need to look into setting ACLs to get to where you need to be - and ACLs may only get you partway there.